# fix number of result in plugin searchWP

Tags: search, plugins

how can I fix number of result in search page instead of percentage in plugin SearchWP

here I have added link of plugin ,which are using in my site : 
searchwp.com

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is. You are using the SearchWP plugin in your site and instead of all results you want just a fixed number? You should provide some screenshots of your current situation and the desired situation.

Comment: sorry for late reply 
Please see link for image  : " demo.wordpresshelper.org/18/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/results.png "
You can see there is dropdown for number of post and search result display with pagination , but number of post are less then 20